# P value difference between FISHER exact test and GLM

Tags: r, glm, p-value

I have a dateset plink.raw and I am testing if a maker CN00020133 (has three level 0, 1, 2) is associated with phenotype5. I want to compare 0 vs 1 and 2 vs 1 using GLM or fisher extract test:

```
    table(plink.raw$phenotype5,plink.raw$CN00020133)
              1     0     2
        0  3559     0     7
        1 14806    54   123
```

1. tested using GLM, I can see the p value for 0 vs 1 is 0.912894.

   ```
   plink.raw$CN00020133 <- factor(plink.raw$CN00020133, levels=c("1","0","2"))
   univariate=glm(phenotype5 ~ relevel(CN00020133,ref ="1"), family = binomial, data = plink.raw)
   summary(univariate)
   ```

   Call:

   ```
   glm(formula = phenotype5 ~ relevel(CN00020133, ref = "1"), 
       family = binomial, data = plink.raw)
   ```

   Deviance Residuals:

   ```
       Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
   -2.4173   0.6564   0.6564   0.6564   0.6564
   ```

   Coefficients:

   ```
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
   (Intercept)                         1.42555    0.01867  76.361  < 2e-16 ***
   relevel(CN00020133, ref = "1")0  13.14051  120.12616   0.109 0.912894    
   relevel(CN00020133, ref = "1")2   1.44072    0.38902   3.703 0.000213 ***

   ---
   Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

   (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

   Null deviance: 18158  on 18548  degrees of freedom
   Residual deviance: 18114  on 18546  degrees of freedom
   AIC: 18120

   Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 13
   ```
2. But if I tested it using fisher exact test, p value for 0 vs 1 is 4.618e-06.

   ```
   Convictions <- matrix(c(0, 54, 3559, 14806), nrow = 2,dimnames = list(c("control", "case"),c("del/dup", "normal_copy")))
   fisher.test(Convictions, alternative = "less")

   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
   data:  Convictions
   p-value = 9.048e-06
   alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is less than 1
   95 percent confidence interval:
   0.0000000 0.2374411
   sample estimates:
   odds ratio 0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have a case of complete separation, also known as The Hauck-Donner effect occurs. If you CN00020133==0, all of them have 1 as phenotype, and this makes it hard to estimate the standard error of the coefficient. There's a fair amount of material on it, for example [Alexej's blog](https://www.alexejgossmann.com/MixedModels_p_values_and_CI/), [post by Brian Ripley](http://math.yorku.ca/Who/Faculty/Monette/S-news/0027.html), [Ben Bolker's notes](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/s4c03/notes/week5.pdf).

If you need to test for significance of the effect of "1", one solution is to use the likelihood ratio test:

```
df =  rbind(
data.frame(phenotype=rep(0:1,c(3559,14806)),CN00020133="1"),
data.frame(phenotype=rep(0:1,c(0,54)),CN00020133="0")
)

anova(glm(phenotype ~ CN00020133,data=df,family=binomial),test="Chisq")

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: phenotype

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


           Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                       18418      18082             
CN00020133  1   23.227     18417      18059 1.44e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This gives you different p-value compared to fisher test because it's a different distribution (binomial vs hyper-geometric). But more or less you can conclude there is an added effect of "1" using "0" as reference.

There is a implementation of Firth's logistic regression in R, you can try and see but I must say I am not very familiar with this:

```
library("logistf")
logistf(phenotype ~ CN00020133,data=df,family=binomial)
```